# Pl Sql Decode and Unzip

Tags: sql, decode

I have the below Java script which works but runs into issues at times. I need to try and write it as Pl Sql which I can then work with inside the application. I can get to the point of base64_decode but I can not get UTL_COMPRESS.LZ_UNCOMPRESS to work. Any ideas, suggestions, please?

Bellow is the working(ish) java code i need to emulate in Pl SQL

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.zip.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
//import org.apache.bob;


public class decompress {

public static void main(String[] args) {

//String zpl = "rVrbbhw5kn33V+hlgV1sWg7mjVk9wADMqmRnVkmyWlK37cGiAE2PVnb3WDbc02uMH/phsT8x
```

this is a very long string staored as a clob in the data base .
6kwF4z6vyGzQYdMKVlUUj1lsWrJJlABbPLdfYvz7xzZVbzZv/7DPwE=";

```
try{
    String zpl = args[0];
    if (zpl.length()&lt;2) {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
        } else {
        //System.out.println(zpl);
        //byte[] res = decompress(zpl.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        Base64 b64 = new Base64();
        byte[] res=Base64.decodeBase64(zpl);
        //System.out.println(new String(res, "UTF-8"));
        byte[] decom=decompress(res);
        System.out.println(new String(decom,"UTF-8"));
    }
    //System.out.println("THIS " + res.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    //e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("ERROR");
}
}

public static byte[] decompress(byte[] data) throws IOException, DataFormatException {
    Inflater inflater = new Inflater(true);
    inflater.setInput(data);

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    while (!inflater.finished()) {
        int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }

    outputStream.close();
    byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();
    inflater.end();

    return output;
}
}
```

SQL Function attempt which seam to do teh base 64 bit but falls apart when trying to decompress.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION decode_base64_x(
p_clob_in IN CLOB)
RETURN BLOB
IS
v_blob BLOB ;
v_result BLOB ;
v_offset INTEGER;
v_buffer_size binary_integer := 48;
v_buffer_varchar VARCHAR2(48);
v_buffer_raw raw(48);
l_uncompressed_blob BLOB ;
l_in_blob BLOB;
BEGIN
IF p_clob_in IS NULL THEN
RETURN NULL;
END IF;


dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_blob, true);
v_offset := 1;
FOR i IN 1 .. ceil(dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob_in) / v_buffer_size)
LOOP
dbms_lob.read(p_clob_in, v_buffer_size, v_offset, v_buffer_varchar);
v_buffer_raw := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_buffer_varchar);
v_buffer_raw := utl_encode.base64_decode(v_buffer_raw);
dbms_lob.writeappend(v_blob, utl_raw.length(v_buffer_raw), v_buffer_raw);
v_offset := v_offset + v_buffer_size;
END LOOP;
v_result := v_blob;
-- 
-- 
-- l_in_blob := (UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (v_blob) );
-- 
UTL_COMPRESS.LZ_UNCOMPRESS( src => v_blob, dst => l_uncompressed_blob);
-- 
dbms_lob.freetemporary(v_blob);
-- l_uncompressed_blob := UTL_COMPRESS.LZ_UNCOMPRESS( src => v_blob ) ;
-- UTL_COMPRESS.lz_uncompress (src => v_blob , dst => l_uncompressed_blob);
-- RETURN l_uncompressed_blob;
RETURN v_result;
END decode_base64_x;
```

i think that its just the UTL_COMPRESS.LZ_UNCOMPRESS bit i am getting wrong !

Comment: Are you getting an error on executing the stored proc, if yes what is it?

Comment: Hello i have tweeked the code a bit to the below which is giveing the following error

Comment: Hello i have tweeked the code a bit which now gives the following error       Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "DCSDBA.DECODE_BASE64_X", line 42
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"

Comment: Below is the code tweek
dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_blob2, true);
v_offset2 := 1;
FOR i2     IN 1 .. ceil(dbms_lob.getlength(v_result) / v_buffer_size2)
LOOP
dbms_lob.read(v_result, v_buffer_size2, v_offset2, v_buffer_varchar2);
v_buffer_raw2 := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_buffer_varchar2);
dbms_lob.writeappend(v_blob2, utl_raw.length(v_buffer_raw2), v_buffer_raw2);
v_offset2 := v_offset2 + v_buffer_size2;
END LOOP;
v_result2 := v_blob2;
dbms_lob.freetemporary(v_blob);
dbms_lob.freetemporary(v_blob2);
return v_result2;
RETURN UTL_COMPRESS.LZ_UNCOMPRESS( src => v_result2) ;
END decode_base64_x;